# Mass Delete AccountContact Relationship Record

Tags: bulk-delete, accountcontactrelation

I have activated the AccountContactRelationship object.

One particular contact is related to 800 Accounts. This is causing issues when we Update records from Dataloader or any other ETL tool.

How can I delete the relationship in bulk without having to manually delete the relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward. You just want to leave the primary account relationship as you cannot delete that (since a contact needs a parent account).

1. Using [dataloader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm), you can export the records with the appropriate query on AccountContactRelation (`WHERE ContactId = yourContactId AND IsDirect = false)` and then run the Ids returned in a delete
2. You could even use a quick anonymous apex script to delete the records since it's all the relationships to a particular contact

```
List< AccountContactRelation > accountContacts = [
    SELECT Id 
    FROM AccountContactRelation 
    WHERE ContactId = 'put Id here' AND IsDirect = false];

delete accountContacts;
```